# Sketchy style – limit letters to 2 in favicon

Tags: feature-request, support, design

*Code Golf*'s name was recently changed to *Programming Puzzles & Code Golf*, so the favicon now reads <sup>P</sup>C<sub>G</sub> instead of <sup>C</sup><sub>G</sub>. My eyes don't like it. Could you change the letter limit in Sketchy favicons to 2? Certainly, in the case of this site, it shouldn't read <sup>P</sup><sub>C</sub>, just change it back to <sup>C</sup><sub>G</sub>.

**Note**: I've also [suggested](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243/design-problems-with-new-logo) to change the name to *Code Golf & Programming Puzzles*.

Comment: The Code Golf favicon has been changed back to `CG`.

Comment: @John I'm still seeing the `PCG` one, though I cleared my cookies, cache and everything yesterday.

Comment: I noticed the favicon in the linked accounts tab and on stackexchange.com/sites both still have `PCG`.  The StackExchange Supercollider Dropdown Menu and the site itself show (to me anyway) `CG`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you only have a problem with that one?

[image: CG]

There are others with three letters and as far as I know nobody's ever said anything:

[image: ITS]

[image: ARP]

[image: DBA]

The letters on the PCG one do seem bigger than the ARP/DBA ones; they don't fit in the boxes. I don't know if fiddling with that would help

Comment: Well, I'm not registered in any other beta sites with a three-letter favicon.

Comment: @Nyu Well, the images are right there :). I'm asking if you have a problem with all three-letter favicons, or if you just think the PCG one is bad